# Operation identifier is not valid

Tags: c#, stream-socket-client

before I start I just want to say that I was looking for solution of this problem for a very long time and I didn't find anything that could help me to solve it.

I need to connect to some server, send a message and display result. It's pretty easy, but it crashes and I have not idea why.

Here is code

```
private async void startMeasurementButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Reading start");
    socket = new StreamSocket();
    var hostName = new HostName("192.168.10.20");
    await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, "10000");
    dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
    dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);

    dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
    dataReader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
    dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    isReading = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Read();
    });
}
```

This works just fine, it connects to server and is ready to work with. And not there is second method

```
private async Task Read()
{
    while (isReading)
    {
        try
        {
            dataWriter.WriteString("1");
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync(); // <== here an exception occurs
            await dataWriter.FlushAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
            IAsyncOperation<uint> taskLoad = dataReader.LoadAsync(8196);
            taskLoad.AsTask().Wait();
            uint bytesToRead = taskLoad.GetResults();
            reading1Voltage.Text = bytesToRead.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In selected line code crashes and throws "Operation identifier is not valid". I tried to do the same thing I did with *LoadAsync*

```
IAsyncOperation<uint> taskLoad = dataReader.LoadAsync(8196);
taskLoad .AsTask().Wait();
```

but it doesn't work. *reading1Voltage* is XAML control, TextBox.

What is wrong with this code and how can I make it work?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't help.

Comment: OK I guess I solved it :) problem was in line **dataWriter.DetachStream();**, I removed it and it works now.